# Add new user and password to debian via SSH with PHP

Tags: php, ssh, debian

I have problem to input a password for new user that generated via ssh with php to a Debian Server.
To add new user I just simpy write "useradd $username". But if I want to set the password for that user it should be like "passwd $username" and then I should insert the password. But how to do this in PHP?

This is my complete code :

```
<?php
$username = "abcd";
$password = "456789";
$expired = "5";
if (!function_exists("ssh2_connect")) die("function ssh2_connect doesn't exist");
// log in at server1.example.com on port 22
if(!($con = ssh2_connect("128.199.xxx.xx", 22))){
echo "fail: unable to establish connection\n";
} else {
// try to authenticate with username root, password secretpassword
if(!ssh2_auth_password($con, "root", "xxxxxx")) {
    echo "fail: unable to authenticate\n";
} else {
    // allright, we're in!
    echo "okay: logged in...\n";

    // execute a command
    if (!($stream = ssh2_exec($con, "passwd 'haha'"))){
        echo "fail: unable to execute command\n";
    } else {
        // collect returning data from command
        stream_set_blocking($stream, true);
        $data = "";
        while ($buf = fread($stream,4096)) {
            $data .= $buf;
        }
        echo "Username berhasil dibuat";
        echo $data;
        fclose($stream);
}
}
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems you are looking for non-interactive way of changing user password.

Try this

`echo "username:newpass"|chpasswd`

Here is [`chpasswd`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/chpasswd.8.html) manual page.

> This method also suits for changing passwords for larger number of users.

**UPD:**

To know currently logged in username [`whoami`](http://www.linfo.org/whoami.html) can be of use.

Comment: Sorry but I still didn't understand, can I just change my code to this :
'if (!($stream = ssh2_exec($con, '"username:newpass"|chpasswd'))){'
@Paul

Comment: You need to substitute currently active username to achieve what you want. For this purpose you can use `whoami` which I added to the answer. First you read current username, than substituting it before `:` and next put your new password as plain text instead of `newpass`.